# how arrange table at row-major order?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, datatable

I am trying to insert an inverse genomic matrix in a linear model and I have to configure the matrix table (3 columns) in row-major order.
how can I arrange table at row-major order using R?
I have the following data:

```
df <- structure(list(Row = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "factor"), Column = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "factor"), 
 Value = c(-2.14424328149392, 0.455084003209218, 1.09147975474287, 
 0.386537649614266, 0.641410247140572, 0.230313748499927, 
 0.455084003209218, -2.03652325941703, 0.405456268069625, 
 0.745804117022615, 0.390015654003772, 0.763870157126766, 
 1.09147975474287, 0.405456268069625, -2.70237121275361, 0.609052056037185, 
 0.521208059539756, 0.418757816250225, 0.386537649614266, 
 0.745804117022615, 0.609052056037185, -2.45518835473028, 
 0.242194496714032, 1.08744294655876, 0.64141024714057, 0.390015654003772, 
 0.521208059539757, 0.242194496714033, -1.79500403824968, 
 0.830661904559763, 0.230313748499928, 0.763870157126766, 
 0.418757816250225, 1.08744294655876, 0.830661904559762, -3.27719947889343
 )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -36L), rowNames = c("1", 
"1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "5", "5", "5", "5", "6", "6", "6", "6"), colNames = c("1", 
"1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "5", "5", "5", "5", "6", "6", "6", "6"), INVERSE = TRUE)
```

I expect the following row and column arrange:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Row = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L
), Column = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), 
Value = c(4.61141258, 
          0.08410074, 2.55757257, 0.27205901, 0.3718584, 3.67049745, 0.68322357, 
          0.14718862, -0.74101976, 5.36935878)), INVERSE = TRUE, row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Do you need `df1[order(df1$Row),]`

Comment: @akrun, it doesn't work, because i need to set the column order in function the number of repetition of the row. like this: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhTbFzVflhrTiKBR_kBChhg2X0twZA?e=m0S76k

Comment: Do you need `dfn %>% group_by(Row) %>% mutate(Column = row_number()) %>% ungroup %>% arrange(Row)`

Comment: I was looking at your link.  It shows similar order only

Comment: yes, similar order only. I've been working on change the matrix before make the table, but also doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear to me as the order i suggested is also giving the similar output.  Can you please update the post with the expected for that example

Comment: Done! please find above.

Comment: In the expected, you have less number of values in 'Column', is it a summarised output you are seeking?

Comment: If I do `df %>% arrange(Row)`, it does the 'arrange' by 'Row'.  But your expected seems to be a different summarised output

Comment: Do you need `df %>% arrange(Row) %>% group_by(Row) %>% filter(as.integer(Column) <= as.integer(first(Row)))`

Answer (score 0):

We could `filter` after converting to `integer`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    arrange(Row) %>% 
    group_by(Row) %>% 
    filter(as.integer(Column) <= as.integer(first(Row)))
```